# Report Viewer Error Framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I'm using the web component of Report Viewer in a project with framework 4. When I change a selected value in a drop down of a parameter the application gets blocked, and just the loading message remains. I don't know if I need to configure the script manager or something else.

Since the component is rendered these errors show up:

> Agente de usuario: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Fecha: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 22:19:26 UTC
>
> Mensaje: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._HoverImage has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.
>   Línea: 785
>   Carácter: 42
>   Código: 0
>   URI: `https://Server/nmxeservices/eservices/RepVentas/ScriptResource.axd?d=c1VzySeHl4YwO9dCq2lZXLdX-YgogXSsDhgzTW2fIP1PFYczn4peaWb3wfmvzWT-vn1mU0mbAZnyTbfMZeAJByiIdijmVcbstfQBkHxSnns1&t=16ab2387`
>
> Mensaje: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The script 'Timer.js' has been referenced multiple times. If referencing Microsoft AJAX scripts explicitly, set the MicrosoftAjaxMode property of the ScriptManager to Explicit.
>   Línea: 984
>   Carácter: 9
>   Código: 0
>   URI: `https://Server/nmxeservices/eservices/RepVentas/ScriptResource.axd?d=c1VzySeHl4YwO9dCq2lZXLdX-YgogXSsDhgzTW2fIP1PFYczn4peaWb3wfmvzWT-vn1mU0mbAZnyTbfMZeAJByiIdijmVcbstfQBkHxSnns1&t=16ab2387`

Web page error details:

> Agente de usuario: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
>   Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Fecha: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 22:19:33 UTC
>
> Mensaje: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._HoverImage has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.
>   Línea: 785
>   Carácter: 42
>   Código: 0
>   URI: `https://Server/nmxeservices/eservices/RepVentas/ScriptResource.axd?d=c1VzySeHl4YwO9dCq2lZXLdX-YgogXSsDhgzTW2fIP1PFYczn4peaWb3wfmvzWT-vn1mU0mbAZnyTbfMZeAJByiIdijmVcbstfQBkHxSnns1&t=16ab2387`
>
> Mensaje: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The script 'Timer.js' has been referenced multiple times. If referencing Microsoft AJAX scripts explicitly, set the MicrosoftAjaxMode property of the ScriptManager to Explicit.
>   Línea: 984
>   Carácter: 9
>   Código: 0
>   URI: `https://Server/nmxeservices/eservices/RepVentas/ScriptResource.axd?d=c1VzySeHl4YwO9dCq2lZXLdX-YgogXSsDhgzTW2fIP1PFYczn4peaWb3wfmvzWT-vn1mU0mbAZnyTbfMZeAJByiIdijmVcbstfQBkHxSnns1&t=16ab2387`